# How should we import local Angular Library in Angular 17?

Tags: angular, angular17

My goal is to create a Angular Library called `header` and `footer` and it will be imported by Angular application such as `featureA` and `featureB`.

The problem is that I am not sure how to import Angular Library to an Angular Application.

This is what I plan to do:

```
import { HeaderComponent } from '../../../../../../../projects/header/src/public-api';
```

The repository: https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/angular-test-17

pass-data-between-components.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CheckoutSelectionComponent } from '../../components/checkout-selection/checkout-selection.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../../../../../../../projects/header/src/public-api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pass-data-between-components',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CheckoutSelectionComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: './pass-data-between-components.page.html',
  styleUrl: './pass-data-between-components.page.scss'
})
export class PassDataBetweenComponentsPage {
  constructor(
  ) {
  }
}
```

I was avoiding this before Angular 17 because it will burden the compiler. But since Angular 17 will only load a component when it is visited for the 1st time, I am tempted to do this.

Note:

1. Before Angular 17, I would build the Angular Library first, then import the dist of the library.
2. I tried to `npm run build` then do `npm run serve:ssr:test-17`, it works.

Is importing Angular Library directly / without building it ok?

Comment: If the code is inside `node_modules` (built code) meaning the dist folder contents, only then its considered a library, what you mention, is a module in an angular project! There is no need to package it in a library right?

Comment: For the development of the libraries, why did you put the library code in a separate project and you did not use the "shared" folder to put the reusable code?
If the code doesn't compile, can you run "ng serve" in the main project and show the error?

Comment: @LPGTESOFTS I put the library code in a separate project because we have `subdomainA` and `subdomainB`. Hence, the need of 2 angular applications. But in Angular 17, I will drop Angular Library then since Vite lazy load the component.

Comment: @NarenMurali there was a need because the app was so slow, I thought to put shared components as compiled library so the Angular compiler don't need to compile the shared components.

Comment: @JasonRichDarmawan But that will happen only if your compiled library is in node_modules, so build and pack the shared modules into a gzip and place in the assets folder, then point package.json to the local file

Comment: @NarenMurali hmm I found that unnecessary. I was able to point it to `dist` folder, component which import will import something like this `@lib/header`

Comment: Currently the current name is "name": "header" in the library project, I guess you need to change the name to "name": "@lib/header" in the package.json file if you want to use the format @lib/header .